# ACF select box css color change

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have trouble with Advanced custom post

I tried to add select box "K dispozicii is "free"  and "Obsazeno" is "occupied"
and I need to change colors green for free, red for occupied

here is the code

```
<p><?php the_field("status"); ?> </p>
```

and the site http://senior-komplex.cz/byty-pro-seniory-melnik-2/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the field value in a variable and use the get_field() instead of the_field() function. From there you can introduce your own custom control structure to set the color you want.

Here is a snippet

```
     <?php 
   //store the value in a variable first
   $option = get_field("status"); 
    if($option=="K dispozicii"){
     ?> <p style="color:green">$option</p> <?php
        }elseif ($option=="Obsazeno") {
           ?> <p style="color:red">$option</p> <?php 
        }
    ?>
```